# Android Studio - Debugging starts as soon as phone is connected with constant logcat stream

Tags: android

Apologies if this seems like a silly question - but I'm fairly new to Android Studio.

I'm currently developing an android application using Android Studio. I started my project on one computer and have had to relocate to another one to continue.

When I open my application in Android Studio and connect my phone to the computer via USB, it immediately starts 'debugging' with a constant stream of messages in the logcat. This did not happen on my previous computer and nothing in the project has changed.

I have launched the Device monitor to try end the process but the 'stop' button is shaded out when my device is selected so I am unable to end it that way.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: I think that is information on all activity on the device, not just activity of your app. Perhaps you had the log level set differently before?

Comment: Yes, I must have had it set differently! Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a valid and expected behaviour, it shows the overall stream of log generated by the phone, for example it may be a combined stream of logs for applications installed and system processes etc.

If you need to debug your own application, then run/debug the application and filter the logs according to the application's package name.

You can read more on :
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have 'Log Level' set to verbose, try setting it to 'Info' or any of the other levels in the drop down menu in the 'Android Monitor' tab at the bottom of Android Studio.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your response :)

Comment: Pleasure... You can accept both our correct answers by clicking the ticks next to them. :)

Comment: I have to wait another minute before i can accept apparently - but I will as soon as I can

Comment: Oh, you accepted it and the unaccepted it...never mind at least you're sorted.